# Line breaks don't work properly when fontspec uses as main font some fonts different from default Latex font

Tags: fonts, line-breaking, fontspec

I have the following code setting as main font `GFSArtemisia` containing just two paragraphs of text with some empty spaces to be completed from students. I noticed that if I use as main font some fonts other than the default font of `LaTeX` as `GFSArtemisia`, `Comic Sans`, `Segoe Script`, `STIX Two Text` and probably other than I haven't checked, the line breaks does not work properly as you can see in the picture below. How can be fixed than manually placing `\linebreak` at the end of each line that have not the right line break? Please note: If you comment the 7th line of the code below: `\setmainfont{GFSArtemisia}\setsansfont{FiraSans}\setmonofont{Consolas}` then the result has no problems. Here is the MWE:

```
% !TeX program = lualatex
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper, total={180mm,257mm},left=15mm,top=20mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
\defaultfontfeatures{Scale=MatchLowercase, Script=Greek}\defaultfontfeatures[\rmfamily]{Scale=1.1}
\setmainfont{GFSArtemisia}\setsansfont{FiraSans}\setmonofont{Consolas}
\newcommand\dotfillin[1][4cm]{\makebox[#1]{\dotfill}}


\begin{document}
    \doublespacing
    
    \noindent This is a text \dotfillin[5cm] containing some empty \dotfillin[5cm] spaces to be completed from \dotfillin[5cm] students, but if set main font to some other fonts like \dotfillin[5cm] STIX Two Tesxt, Comic Sans, Segoe Script, GFS Artemisia and others \dotfillin[5cm] the linebreaks \dotfillin[5cm] does not work properly \dotfillin[5cm]. How can be fixed \dotfillin[5cm]?
    
    \noindent Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing  \dotfillin[5cm] elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et \dotfillin[5cm] dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim \dotfillin[5cm] veniam, quis nostrud \dotfillin[5cm] exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit \dotfillin[5cm] in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu \dotfillin[5cm] fugiat nulla pariatur. \dotfillin[5cm] excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia \dotfillin[5cm] deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: why should there be linebreaks? your dots are in a box.

Comment: Why the box is not send as a whole in the next line? And why the same problem does not occur with the default font of Latex and some other fonts as GFSNeohellenic?

Comment: Different fonts, different linebreaks. Beside this you are scaling the font and so there is less on the line. Use \raggedright. (And I wouldn't use Script=Greek for a latin text.)

Comment: @Ulrike Fischer: You have right about Script=Greek, I forgot it there when I was writing the MWE, but make no difference if I remove it. Scaling sometimes is necessary, so I cannot avoid it. I will follow your advice to use \raggedright.

Comment: @Ulrike Fischer: Unfortunately, \raggedright does not produce the desired result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding `\sloppy` resolves all overflow boxes in this example.

[image: a]

```
% !TeX program = lualatex
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper, total={180mm,257mm},left=15mm,top=20mm,showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
\defaultfontfeatures{Scale=MatchLowercase}\defaultfontfeatures[\rmfamily]{Scale=1.1}
\setmainfont{GFSArtemisia}\setsansfont{FiraSans}\setmonofont{Consolas}
\newcommand\dotfillin[1][4cm]{\makebox[#1]{\dotfill}}
    
\begin{document}
    \sloppy % <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
    
    \doublespacing
    
    \noindent This is a text \dotfillin[5cm] containing some empty \dotfillin[5cm] spaces to be completed from \dotfillin[5cm] students, but if set main font to some other fonts like \dotfillin[5cm] STIX Two Tesxt, Comic Sans, Segoe Script, GFS Artemisia and others \dotfillin[5cm] the linebreaks \dotfillin[5cm] does not work properly \dotfillin[5cm]. How can be fixed \dotfillin[5cm]?
    
    \noindent Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing  \dotfillin[5cm] elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et \dotfillin[5cm] dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim \dotfillin[5cm] veniam, quis nostrud \dotfillin[5cm] exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit \dotfillin[5cm] in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu \dotfillin[5cm] fugiat nulla pariatur. \dotfillin[5cm] excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia \dotfillin[5cm] deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
    
\end{document}
```

A similar result is generated with `\setlength{\emergencystretch}{2em}`